# python import error for other python files

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I am running on python 3.5 on Windows 10
I have a directory, which has inside some python scripts
for example
one is called `pfm.py` and the other is called `data.py`

I want to import pfm into data

inside the `data.py` , I wrote `import pfm` and i receive this error

```
    import pfm
ImportError: No module named 'pfm'
```

Folder PATH Listing is

```
C:.
├───data
│   ├───lib
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
```

`data.py` and `pfm.py` are inside data folder
and the `main.py` which I am running is outside in the main directory

Comment: in console in root dict use `tree` command and post the output in your question

Comment: `Folder PATH listing for volume Windows
Volume serial number is 000000E0 5C55:A5FC
C:.
├───lib
│   └───__pycache__
└───__pycache__`

Comment: add the files directory path to `sys.path.append('Your directory')`

Comment: @SuryaTej It is already in the same directory

Comment: Try `from . import pfm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to write:

```
 from . import pfm
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running your main script from outside the folder, you have to specify which package your code lies in. If `data` were to be in the python path, you could use `import data.pfm`.

I suspect, that it is not in your python path, so you need to specify, that you are importing something relative to your current package. Thus, use

```
import .pfm
```

It will use the current package (`data`).

**Note** that doing this, you cannot call `data.py` by itself, as this will not provide the neccessary local packaging information.

Answer (score 0):

Before **import pfm** in **data.py** script,you can define the base location of your project where all your python script is exists after that you can **import pfm**.For example

```
import sys
sys.path.append("your project base location where pfm script is written")
import pfm
```